# How to use spring data cassandra & elasticsearch configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch, spring-data-cassandra

I'm trying to use both Spring Data Cassandra & Spring Data ElasticSearch in an Spring Boot application.
I already put Cassandra Repository & ElasticSearch Repository in different packages.

```
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.my.app.es.repository")
public class ElasticsearchConfig {
   ...
}

@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "com.my.app.cassandra.repository" })
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {
   ...
}
```

When I tried to run, I got the following exception::

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converter' defined in class path resource [com/my/app/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CassandraConverter]: Factory method 'converter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method CassandraConfig.mappingContext called as a bean reference for type [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext]. Overriding bean of same name declared in: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same issue, I was using this to created CassandraConverter() object and using the constructor with CassandraMappingContext which was creating the issue.

Issue:-

```
@Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraConverter converter() {
        return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext()); //Remove this and call MappingCassandraConverter() with passing any arguement.
    }
```

To fix this i replaced above with:-

```
@Bean
    public CassandraConverter converter() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new MappingCassandraConverter();
    }
```

And rest piece of code remains same of setting this converter in CassandraSessionFactoryBean()

If your problem is not solved please provide the snippet, i will provide the correct configuration.

Comment: Can you have a look at my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353603/spring-data-elastic-search-and-spring-data-cassandra-having-issues-with-mapid